# The file size exceed the configured limit. Code insight features are not avaible

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy intentado abrir un archivo de mi proyecto pero me salta este aviso:

> "The file size exceed the configured limit. Code insight features are
>   not avaible".

Hay alguna forma de modificar el límite del tamaño?

Saludos y gracias

El error me aparece en Android Studio

Comment: en qué programa especificamente te está produciendo el error?

Comment: @Gabriel Gonzales perdón se me ha olvidado es en Android Studio

Comment: Anda a la pestaña help > Edit Custom Properties

agrega "idea.max.intellisense.filesize=999999"

Comment: @Gabriel Gonzales lo acabo de probar pero me sale el mismo mensaje

Comment: reiniciaste Android Studio?

Comment: @Gabriel Gonzales ahora si jajaja, muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo la respuesta aquí

> Anda a la pestaña help > Edit Custom Properties agrega
>   "idea.max.intellisense.filesize=999999"

y reiniciar

Comment: Creo que es suficiente con subir solo de 2500 kb a un valor mayor, 999999 es excesivo  :-\

Comment: cierto, pero cada quien lo configurará a su manera

Answer (score 2):

Si obtienes el mensaje :

> The file size exceed the configured limit. Code insight features are
>   not avaible.

Esto se debe a que tu archivo excede el tamaño definido en la IDE, **el tamaño default definido para un archivo es 2500 kilobytes**, puedes editarlo de esta forma, ve a

`Help` > `Edit Custom Properties` y si no tienes el archivo `idea.properties` créalo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y define el tamaño máximo en kilobytes, ejemplo:

```
idea.max.intellisense.filesize=3500
```

al agregar esta configuración personalizada es necesario reiniciar `Android Studio`.

---

Puedes revisar la configuración para [InteliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/) que aplican para `Android Studio`:

[**Configuración de propiedades de plataforma**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#configure-platform-properties)